# c# cannot start the service error 1053

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

I developed a service and I installed to my machine succesfully. And when I wanna to start the service, error 1053 appears. So If you don't know about error 1053:

[See what I got](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839174)

I tried the solution which included in the link. But it still has this error. So what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You service is starting too long. Probably it failed or thrown exception durring startup.

You can attach debugger to this process to see what is wrong. To attach debbuger ow service statup you can try this link: http://gan-r.blogspot.com/2011/09/debugging-windows-services.html

Comment: Ah thank you really. Your and jgauffin's answers are same but I will accept you because your first.

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong during startup.

The easiest way to find out why is to run the service as a console application. What you do is simply to attach a console using [AllocConsole](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.allocconsole) as I describe [here](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/an-easier-way-to-debug-windows-services/).